# Why doesn't my autocomplete work MVC3 Razor Engine

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, autocomplete

I using code from this blog [Autocompletion Textbox in MVC Using jQuery](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/miah/archive/2008/11/13/autocompletion-textbox-in-mvc-using-jquery.aspx)

but my jQuery isn't firing. I suspect its to do with my selector. I am using MVC as well but I don't see how that would make the javascript any different.

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using UserManager.Models;

namespace UserManager.Controllers
{
    public class UserManagerController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /UserManager/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            try
            {
                var data = new UserManager.Models.UserManagerTestEntities();
                return View(data.vw_UserManager_Model_Add_Users.ToList());

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return View(ViewBag);
            }

        }

        public ActionResult CreateUser()
        {

            var data = new UserManager.Models.UserManagerTestEntities();
            ViewBag.Message = "Create New User";
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult LookUpGroupName(string q, int limit)
        {
            //TODO: Map list to autocomplete textbox control
            DAL d = new DAL();
            List<string> groups = d.groups();

            var GroupValue = groups
                .Where(x => x.StartsWith(q))
                .OrderBy(x => x)
                .Take(limit)
                .Select(r => new { group = r });

            // Return the result set as JSON
            return Json(GroupValue, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
}

@model UserManager.Models.vw_UserManager_Model_Add_Users
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create New User";
}
<h2>
    CreateUser</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>New User Details</legend>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(Model => Model.salutation)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => Model.salutation)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => Model.salutation)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(Model => Model.firstname)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => Model.firstname)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => Model.firstname)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(Model => Model.lastname)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => Model.lastname)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => Model.lastname)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(Model => Model.password)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => Model.password)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => Model.password)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(Model => Model.email)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => Model.email)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => Model.email)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(Model => Model.isactive)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => Model.isactive)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => Model.isactive)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.Label("Group Name")
            <!-- GroupName -->
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => Model.group_name)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => Model.group_name)
        </div>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>

    <div>
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
    </div>
}
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#group_name").autocomplete('@Url.Action("LookUpGroupName")', 
        {
        dataType: 'json',
        parse: function (data) {
            var rows = new Array();
            alert("before loop");
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                rows[i] = { data: data[i], value: data[i].group, result: data[i].group }
            }
            return rows;
        },
        formatItem: function (row, i, max) {
            return row.group
        },
        width: 300,
        highlight: false,
        multiple: true,
        multipleseparator: ","
    });
});

</script>
```

HTML rendered to browser:

```
<input name="group_name" class="text-box single-line" id="group_name" type="text" value=""/>
```

Probably something simple I just cant see it. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: is your alert before loop showing?

Comment: Nope, which is why I suspect the selector isn't finding the ID I am supplying it with.

Comment: check $("#group_name").lenght before autocomplete call,this will assure your html having an element group_name or not

Comment: I used alert($("#group_name").length); and it contained 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using MVC3 Razor this syntax will not work:

```
$("#postTags").autocomplete('<%=Url.Action("LookUpGroupName",) %>',
```

This is because Razor Engine doesn't understand WebForms Engine Syntax. Instead I used:

```
$("#group_name").autocomplete('@Url.Action("LookUpGroupName")',
```

I used the overloaded method which accepts ActionResult name only. This worked for me but you if your solution is setup differently you might have to supply both Controller and ActionResult arguements.

Finally I was getting error code 500 when my AJAX request was being made. This is because in my LookUpGroupName method I had to refactor this line of code:

```
return Json(GroupValue);
```

To:

```
return Json(GroupValue, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

My original post has all the correct code for anybodys future reference.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe `@Html.EditorFor(model => Model.group_name)` adds and ID to the element it creates, therefor your selector will not match. You could add an ID like this:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => Model.group_name, new { ID = "group_name"})
```

In addition, if you wan't to select on an ID with jquery it is better to use the ID-selector `#group_name` instead, unless you actually have a number of elements where the ID actually start with `group_name` for all of them, and you want to select all of the elements at once.

**Update**

You use the [attribute start with](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) selector `input[id^=group_name`, and have a typo in it. You are missing the closing `]` in your selector. Even so, if you don't intent to select multiple elements that all have ID's that start with `group_name`, which your markup indicate that you don't. Then you should really use the ID selector instead.

Comment: Ok I used #group_name first but that didn't work and from viewing HTML source I can see it has an id of group name.

Comment: Could it be a razor engine issue. I noticed its using <% %> when its an @ for mvc3

Comment: @nickgowdy That's a good catch, that looks like the web forms syntax. What does the generate URL look like if you look at the HTML-source?

Comment: I have script error in my console when using F12 developer tools in ie9.                                                                  SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'autocomplete' 
CreateUser, line 100 character 9

Comment: @nickgowdy Are you sure you have referenced the autocomplete-plugin? Sounds like that could be the issue then.

Comment: I added the autocomplete plugin and now there is no error but it doesn't fire the second alert so I think the Webform engine is the last problem.

Comment: @nickgowdy So what happens if you replace the webform syntax with razor syntax `@Url.Action("LookupTags", "UserManager")`. Does it solve your final issue?

Comment: When I use F12 Developer tools in IE I am looking at the Network request and I am getting a Result 404 when the JS Library XMLHTTPRequest is made. Its not finding the right controller/action path

Comment: I feel like an idiot! I was using the actionResult name of the example and not what my one is called. I then in my return Json method I had to specify JsonRequestBehaviour to AllowGet because I was getting error code 500. Thanks for your help I will edit my code to help others.

Answer (score 0):

Do a test run with this

```
 $(function() {
        var availableTags = [
            "ActionScript",
            "AppleScript",
            "Asp",
            "BASIC",
            "Scala",
            "Scheme"
        ];
        $( "#group_name" ).autocomplete({
            source: availableTags
        });
    });
```